# Willmore tori in $S^3$

Tags: dg.differential-geometry

I know that the Clifford torus in $S^3$ is Willmore. I can also think about $S^1$-equivariant tori and Hopf tori as Willmore in the $3$-sphere.

Does anyone know if there are more Willmore tori in $S^3$? Any source, idea or comment is very welcome.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, there are many examples . First of all, there are infinitely many minimal tori (immersed, not embedded ) in the 3-sphere.
There are also minimal surfaces with embedded planar ends of genus one.
Also, there is the Babich-Bobenko paper in which Willmore tori with umbilical lines are constructed.

Comment: In case you could also answer this related question that came to my mind: *are the minimal tori of revolution in $S^3$ the unique Willmore tori of revolution in $S^3$?*

Comment: Yes, willmore tori of revolution are isothermic hence minimal in a space form. This is a result in the thesis of Jörg Richter. All closed examples are minimal in S^3, see for example 'constrained willmore tori and elastic curves' by Lynn Heller.